# Как написать функцию, которая вычисляет угол ABC в радианах, если известны координаты точек B и C?

Tags: python, функции

Нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает угол ABC в радианах.

Параметры функции: B_X, B_Y, C_X, C_Y. B_X - координата X у точки B, B_Y - координата Y у точки B, C_X - координата X у точки C, C_Y - координата Y у точки C. У точек B и A координаты Y равны. Начало координат находится в левом верхнем углу:

[image: Угол]

Answer (score 3):

Для решения данной задачи нужно знать всего две формулы:

- расстояние между двумя точками на плоскости (точки заданы координатами):

  |AB| = ( (xb - xa)<sup>2</sup> + (yb - ya)<sup>2</sup> )<sup>1/2</sup>
- `cos (ABC) = |AB| / |BC|`, следовательно угол `ABC = acos(|AB| / |BC|)`

Для того чтобы найти угол точку `A` можно спроецировать из точки `C` на отрезок `AB`, таким образом вы найдете координаты точки `A'`.

Ну а дальше все это легко реализуется на Python...

Удачи!

Comment: Что значит спроецировать?

Comment: @Lagunov, провести перпендикуляр из точки `C` на отрезок `AB`

Comment: А как спроецировать?

Comment: первую формулу можете  не знать :)  cos = (bx-cx) / (cx-bx)

Comment: @splash58, т.е. угол будет всегда равен 0 градусов (`arccos(1)`)?? :-D

Comment: @Lagunov, возьмите лист бумаги, карандаш и линейку, начертите такую же картинку как у вас в вопросе, проведите перпендикуляр от точки `C` к отрезку `AB` (пусть это будет точка `A'`) и подумайте какие будут координаты у получившейся точки `A'` ...

Comment: @MaxU :) описался. (by-cy) / (cx-bx)

Comment: @splash58, ну тогда это будет все таки тангенс, а не косинус ;)